# Post notes to a facebook page with an Application Api Key

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting an application api key with this request:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

I want to create notes on a user page but it fails. I'm sending a post request with subject and message to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]/notes/access_token=[APP_TOKEN]
```

But what i get is:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#281) Requires extended permission: create_note",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 281
   }
}
```

With an user api key with all permissions, i was just sending a request to /accounts/, then getting the page key and I was able to create notes. But I am confused about application keys. Maybe i just need additional permissions but i don't know how to do it.

This is how the application looks in user's App Center:
[image]

Any ideas?

P.S.: the reason i use an APP key is that it doesn't expire. Simple user keys expire in about 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not ask for permissions for an *app* access token.

What you want to do *requires* a *page* access token.

> P.S.: the reason i use an APP key is that it doesn't expire. Simple user keys expire in about 2 hours.

As has been said here in various discussions about the deprecation of offline_access *multiple times before*:

Page access tokens acquired using a *long-lived* user access token do **not** expire by default.

Comment: If page access tokens(acquired using long-lived tokens) do not expire by default, then this is the solution. Thank you